# Game window flickers

Tags: java, graphics, slick2d

Every couple seconds, the window in which my game is playing will briefly disappear and then reappear. I'm on Windows 7 with the latest version of Slick (a game library for Java). Here's the code I'm using:

```
package Main;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
public class Main extends BasicGame{

    public Main() {
        super("Flashing window issue");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException {
         AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new Main());
         app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
         app.start();

    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

---

Progress so far:

Update: No solution found yet, but playing the game in fullscreen mode eliminates the flicker. Perhaps this will lead to a solution...

Update 2: Monitering the task manager shows that while the game is flickering its status in the task manager is 'Not Responding'.

Update 3: It seems to only happen when the mouse leaves the game area (regardless of whether the game window loses focus).

Update 4 - Current workaround:

```
app.setMouseGrabbed(true); // force the mouse to stay in the game area
```

then in update(...):

```
// exit when escape is pressed:
if (gc.getInput().isKeyDown(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
       gc.exit();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with slick2d but does it have a concept of double buffering?  that would be something you would want to turn on if you get flickering.

Comment: I don't think it's a graphics issue like that. The entire window (including the title bar, and the _OX buttons) disappears and then reappears briefly, which seems unrelated to the kind of issues that could be fixed by double buffering